# Multiply fields inside array of object with autoform in Meteor

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, meteor-autoform, meteor-collection2

I use `collection2` and `autoform` in Meteor.

In my schema, I have a field holding an array of objects.

Each object in the array has fields `quantity` and `price`.

In my template, I output the array of objects with

```
{{#afEachArrayItem name="itemArray"}}
  <tr>
    <td>{{> afFieldInput name=this.current.quantity}}</td>
    <td>{{> afFieldInput name=this.current.price}}</td>
    <td>...</td>
  </tr>
{{/afEachArrayItem}}
```

Instead of `...`, I want the total which is computed as `quantity * price`.

How can I obtain this? I am using `autosave` in my form, so I guess that I can make a collection helper to compute the total for each object in the array and just output it in the template.

I am doing the exact same thing to compute the grand total, i.e. the total of all the individual totals in the array with

```
CollectionName.helpers({
  total() {
    let total = 0;
    if (this.items) {
      this.itemArray.forEach(function(item) {
        if (item && item.quantity && item.price) {
          total += item.quantity * item.price;
        }
      });
    }
    return total;
  },
});
```

Comment: Hi, have you define the template helpers to retrieve the collection helpers into the template scope? (template.yourTemplateName.helpers({total: function () {return CollectionName.total(); }}).

Comment: No. I juse use it directly with `{{#with invoice}}{{#autoForm doc=this ...}}{{{{#afEachArrayItem name="itemArray"}}...{{/afEachArrayItem}}{{/autoForm}}{{total}}{{/with}}`